# list file and using awk to get comment

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

I want to get the all comment of all files in a folder.

And what I have tried is

`ls -R | awk '/<!--/,/-->/' >> result`

But it shows nothing in the result file.

But if I use the `awk '/<!--/,/-->/' >> result` to a file it works.

The html comment tag is `<!-- some text here -->`.

How should I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your awk is looking at the file names and not at the file contents. Here is a better approach:

```
find ./ -type f -execdir grep "<!--.*-->" "{}" +
```

This uses `find` to get a list of all the files and then feeds these into `grep` which searches for the text you are seeking. It will then output the name of any matching file followed by a colon (:) and the text of the matched line.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -R` will list only the file name not a file contents. 
You can do this in a more simple way using `grep` command.

```
grep -rn '<!--.*-->'
```

Or if want to do this using `awk` then you can use `cat *` to list all file content in a directory.

```
cat * | awk '/<!--/,/-->'
```

Note: This approach works only if your directory contains files.

If you want to list all content in all directory. You can try this

```
find . -type f | xargs cat | awk '/<!--/,/-->/'
```